# Capture variable(s) before : from an output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a batch to capture the HH:MM:SS of any files within a directory. I'm not sure what to use in order to capture the minutes and seconds respectively due to the hours not always being double digit.

IE: 4:15:10 PM

so as far as I understand, I cant use variable substrings to grab that information. Is there a way to grab the data before the : within a variable? I need to determine if a file is over 10 minutes old using only batch (no powershell, despite how nice it would be to use).

Here's what I have so far.

```
    cd c:\users\jthompson\desktop\test
    forfiles /m *.txt /c "cmd /c echo @ftime")
    pause
    for /f %%a in ('forfiles /m *.txt /c "cmd /c echo @ftime"') do call c:\users\jthompson\desktop\test2.bat %%a
    pause
```

second script

```
    echo %1
    set var=%1
    set minutes=%var:~3,2%
    set seconds=%var:~6,2%
```

Answer (score 0):

`forfiles` gives me the format `08:25:00` (with the leading zero; 24 hours based). If yours doesn't, just replace the space with a zero. Also there is a better way to get the substrings.

```
set var=%1
echo time is: %var%
set var=%var: =0"
echo time is: %var% - space replaced with zero
REM tokenize the timestring:
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%a in ("%var%") do (
  set hours=%%a
  set minutes=%%b
  set seconds=%%c
)
```